# Import a single global variable from a different module in python

Tags: python, pep8

I have an interesting application and I would like to access a global variable from a different module.

I currently have module x

```
from pkg.mod import *
```

in order to get the namespace `foo`.

where my pkg.mod looks like the following

```
import x
foo = 0
# do some stuff
foo = myClass()
```

That all works just great, however, I would like NOT to do that, mostly just because its bad.

If I try the following

```
from pkg import mod
```

I get a circular dependency issue. `ImportError: cannot import name mod` which makes sense to me.

What I want to do is

```
from pkg.mod import foo
```

but that also gives me an import name error: `ImportError: cannot import name foo`
Which I am not exactly sure why, except I dont think you can import variables specifically.

Is there anyway to import `foo` following correct practices?

---edit---

I have tried to remove the shared variable and put it in a third module in such a way

pkg.y

```
foo = 0
```

pkg.mod

```
from pkg.y import foo
foo = myClass()
x.dostuff()
```

x

```
from pkg.y import foo
def dostuff():
   print(foo)
```

and now x thinks foo is still 0. (I can guarantee that mod is calling x, and thus happening first.)

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` in the pkg folder?

Comment: put the shared bit in yet another file and import it into both files ... thus eliminating the circular dependency

Comment: Putting it in a shared file won't work. Remember, in Python, all variables are references, even variables which contain simple constants like `0`. `from pkg.py import foo` means "go grab `foo` from `pkg.py` and assign local variable `foo` to reference it", then `foo = myClass()` means "call `myClass()` and change `foo` to reference its result", which releases the reference to the `foo` you got from `pkg.py`. Meanwhile `x.foo` still refers to the `foo` in `pkg.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need a true global variable I find it cleaner to create a module called trueglobals.py; it can remain empty but for proper documentation...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Object references that are used extensively across many modules are 
# stored here.

# someObject1      - instantiated in main.py
# someObject2      - instantiated in someothermodule.py
```

In the module instantiating the object...

```
import trueglobals
trueglobals.someObject1 = myClass(somevar)
```

In any module requiring the object...

```
import trueglobals
localVar = trueglobals.someObject1
```